# Получить текст из WebView

Tags: android

В webView загружается текст из БД.

```
txtViewTranslation.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, translate, "text/html", "en_US", null);
```

Текст выглядит как-то так **ываваоаро** ..... и т.д. в общем может быть много тегов различных.

Можно ли как-то получить просто текст из WebView без всяких тегов и записать это в строковую переменную?

Comment: Можно, но придется распарсить страничку. Смотрите примеры по jsoup

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.